# FullCalendar.js adjust header for mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullcalendar

I am using responsive styling in a project that uses the fullcalendar.js.
Unfortunately, I can't get the style of the header (fc-header-left, fc-header-center, fc-header-right) to stack on each other when in mobile view.
For example... in desktop view it looks like...
fc-header-left         fc-header-center          fc-header-right

When mobile I would like the 3 parts of the header to stack on top of each other.
fc-header-left
fc-header-center
fc-header-right

I have tried to override these headers with negative margins, floats and all kinds of things but I can't get these headers to stack.

Does anyone know how I can get the header parts to stack on each other in mobile view?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give each of them a `width:100%;` and `display:block;` that should do the trick.
At least I was able to get the demo one on teh fullcalendar.js website to do that.
You will then have to align them as you see fit.

```
.fc-header-left, fc-header-center, fc-header-right {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**For Fullcalendar v5**

```
@media (max-width: 767.98px) {
    .fc .fc-toolbar.fc-header-toolbar {
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .fc-header-toolbar .fc-toolbar-chunk {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me with the newest version. Check done using screen width.

```
@media (max-width: 768px){
    .fc-toolbar .fc-left, .fc-toolbar .fc-center, .fc-toolbar .fc-right {
        display: inline-block;
        float: none !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: U r my hero, men!

Answer (score 0):

The version I am working with uses flexbox. This is what works for me,

```
.fc-toolbar {
    .fc-center h2 {
        font-size: 1.25em
    }
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    @media (min-width: 600px) {
        display: flex;
    }
}
```